# Danish characters replaced by question mark

Tags: php, character-encoding

I want to remove the question marks from this string which is in Danish.

```
...mest i betydningen moralsk ford�rvelse eller bestikkelighed, men ogs� i...
```

I tried `utf8_encode()` which return the following:

```
...mest i betydningen moralsk fordï¿½rvelse eller bestikkelighed, men ogsï¿½ i...
```

The first string is the response I get in a XML in a web service. Is there a way to fix this from my side?

Comment: What is the input encoding (typically either `ISO-8859-1` or `UTF-8`) and what do you want the output encoding to be?

Comment: hey Mido am I not doing that whe calling utf8_encode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

to set the character encoding to UTF-8 in your page.

As well as making sure that you tell the browser you are using UTF-8, add this to your code:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- rest of code here -->
</head>
```

Also remember that it also depends on when this data is coming from. Check the encoding of the database if it's pulled off a database.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that database queries can also cause mangled characters if not using the correct charset. E.g. in MySQL `SET NAMES UTF8;` may be necessary depending on the setup.

Comment: So @Mido so what you are say is that the problem might be on fetching the data(db query)? I tried the header function abode and it does not solve it.

Comment: There is no workaround considering I have the given string? Given that the header(...) does not work.

Answer (score 4):

Read the `encoding` attribute of the XML file and use that encoding to convert it to the encoding your website is using. If there is no encoding attribute, default to UTF-8. If the encoding resulting form the steps is the same encoding as your website using, no conversion is necessary.

```
$encoding_read_from_xml = "ISO-8859-1";
$encoding_my_website_uses = "UTF-8";
$xml_content = mb_convert_encoding($xml_content, $encoding_my_website_uses, $encoding_read_from_xml);
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way to avoid this kind of problem is, to use UTF-8 for the whole website, that means:

1. Encode the PHP file itself as UTF-8, this is done by your editor/IDE.
2. Add the meta tag to the page, for example `<meta charset="UTF-8">` for HTML5.
3. Maybe the most important point: set the charset of the database connection object to UTF-8 before making queries, for mysqli you could call `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8')`.

When you follow these points, you will never have to convert any data between different encodings. More information and examples you can find in this small article [UTF-8 for PHP and MySQL](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#utf8).

Comment: This is only for internal data, the data he is getting from others can be in any encoding

Comment: @Esailija - You are right, i overlooked that the data comes from a web-service. If the OP cannot change the behaviour of the service, then your answer will be appropriate, otherwise i recommend to let the service deliver UTF-8. +1 for your answer.

Comment: Just occurred to me. The OP is seeing the unicode replacement character on his page, and only as a result of using unicode decoding can you see that character. Then he calls `utf8_encode()`, which results in `ï¿½` when the page is interpreted as UTF-8 and the character to encode was literally `�`. So if this is directly from source, and the op just called `utf8_encode` on it, **the original source must literally** have the character `�` and it is unrecoverable for him. tl;dr: everything is utf-8 correctly but the characters are literally `�` to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Check your input **and** output encoding. In most cases, choosing UTF-8 for both is the best approach.

If your input is in ISO-8859-1, use `utf8_encode()` to encode it to UTF-8. If it already is UTF-8, calling `utf8_encode()` again will mess things up.

To specify the output as UTF-8, use `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` in PHP or `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Adjusting your header as shown below?, I had the same problem, but this clears out things

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```