# Special Characters In Php and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html-entities

I've got a problem with some specials characters in PHP. I have a table in mysql (utf8_hungarian_ci) that contains some text with special characters like  á, á, Ó, Ö, ö, ü, and I would like to show this text on my page. I've tested:

```
$text = htmlentities($text); //to convert the simple spec chars
$search = array("& otilde;","&O tilde;","& ucirc;","&U circ;");
$replace = array("& #337;","& #336;","& #369;","& #368;");
$text = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);
echo $text;
```

But this code works only if $text isn't set from database. If I use this code and my $text is selected from database, it doesn't shows me any text, and if I only use: 
    echo $text; without htmlentities and replacements

I get characters like this one: �

I know there were some questions about this and I have tried accepted answers, but it still doesn't work, so please help me if you want and if you have time. Thank you anyway. A good day to you all!

Comment: Didn't you just asked this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814947/danish-characters-replaced-by-guestion-mark/) Minutes ago?

Comment: What about `htmlspecialchars_decode`?

Comment: @phpNoOb I wonder if it's him too...

Comment: It's the first time I'm asking this question. I haven't saw the question you are talking about so I don't know if there is something useful there

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this in you html header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

(Also, you may need to save your file in "utf-8" file encoding)

.

Secondly, you could use this to try to tranlate-or-remove the disturbing char that always prints out in your case:

```
$str_out = @iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $str_in);
```

Comment: Still doesn't shows me anything. I don't understand why from my database it doesn't receive the same text.

Comment: are you sure its in the database? perhaps those chars were filtered out before that. Also, are you using any sanitization function? or any specialchar function that does encoding (htmlspecialchars_encode)? usually, double encoding destroys the data..

Comment: I am sure. If I store any text with normal characters in my database and then I print it, it works, and when there are special characters in that text, I see normal characters and instead of the special ones, I see signes like this �. I am not using other sanitizatoin function. Thanks anyway for you're try.

Comment: ok, try this:
`$str_out = @iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", $str_in);`

Answer (score 1):

Also try setting in your header to use UTF-8 encoding.

In your PHP file, add

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

as well as specifying the encoding to be UTF-8 in your `<meta>` tag, to ensure that you told the browser. And see if it fixes the issue.

As well as including UTF-8 encoding in your `meta` tag.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
...
</head>
```

Edit:

1. If you have access to Apache configuration, see if AddDefaultCharset is set to another encoding.
2. Try using `mysql_set_charset()` (mysqli_set_charset() if you're using MySQLi).

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly generic answer but please read up this article I wrote on common character-encoding pitfalls in the PHP/MySQL stack and if you still have problems let's try to work through them.

http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/how-to-avoid-character-encoding-problems-in-php/